# Excel - Make a list of values in one column based on non-empty values of another column

Tags: excel

I have the following excel:

[image]

I wish to generate the list to the right based on the table to the left. I am looking for non-empty values in column `A` and generating a list of the corresponding values in column `B`.

I have tried the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A6)),B1:B6,TRUE)
```

and getting `#REF!`. I can't understand why.

Is that a good method? How can I do this?

Comment: What version of Excel?  If 365 you can use `=FILTER(B1:B6,A1:A6<>"")`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook it did the job. kindly make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel 365 you can use the `FILTER` function:

```
=FILTER(B1:B6,A1:A6<>"")
```